# Компания Les râteaux du chaton vert / «Les râteaux du chaton vert»

Tags: орфография

Названия компаний — с кавычками?

> Я через Сбербанк и Роснефть / «Сбербанк» и «Роснефть» миллион долларов получил.

А по-нерусски написанные?

> Моя компания Les râteaux du chaton vert / «Les râteaux du chaton vert» процветает-таки.